# Каким образом сделать такой же TITLE

Tags: html

Увидел на одном сайте - сразу бросается в глаза.
Как напечатать такой же текст?

он не просто жирный

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/

Comment: @andreymal а влияет ли это как-то на сео?

Comment: Ну как минимум скорее всего поисковики такое слово будут игнорировать, ведь технические это не слово, а набор математических символов

Comment: В гугле  ищется, а в яндексе нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легального рабочего метода стилизаровать тег title нет.

Есть вариант просто прописать с помощью [кодировки UTF-8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=119680), но это хреновый метод с точки зрения SEO(потому что слова написанные так не индексируються как слова, и этот ход может восприниматься поисковиками как некий хак) и я не находил инфы по кирилическим символам.

Как по мне больше пользы для выразительсти будет от хорошей фавиконки сделаной под ретину(а с этим часто провтыкивают), а так, это скорее выглядит как перекачка синтолом) Типо красиво в каких то рамках, но с какого то момента появляеться риск ампутации из выдачи